# ivy & server access errors

Tags: ivy

We have an Ivy repository accessible via HTTP. It can be accessed by several machines without problems but on a Windows machine we get a server access error.

```
[ivy:retrieve] Loading jar:file:/C:/Users/moserma/.ant/lib/ivy-2.3.0-rc1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivy.properties
[ivy:retrieve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc1 - 20120416000235 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] jakarta commons httpclient not found: using jdk url handling
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = D:\moserma\newWorkspace\Lakshmi\ivy\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] no default ivy user dir defined: set to C:\Users\moserma\.ivy2
[ivy:retrieve] settings loaded (66ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  default cache: D:\moserma\newWorkspace\Lakshmi\ivy\ivy-cache
[ivy:retrieve]  default resolver: ETHZ-HTTP
[ivy:retrieve]  -- 1 resolvers:
[ivy:retrieve]  ETHZ-HTTP [url]
[ivy:retrieve] no resolved descriptor found: launching default resolve
Overriding previous definition of property "ivy.version"
[ivy:retrieve] using ivy parser to parse file:/D:/moserma/newWorkspace/Lakshmi/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: ch.ethz.wai#Lakshmi;1.0
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  validate = true
[ivy:retrieve]  refresh = false
[ivy:retrieve] resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
[ivy:retrieve] == resolving dependencies for ch.ethz.wai#Lakshmi;1.0 [default]
[ivy:retrieve] == resolving dependencies ch.ethz.wai#Lakshmi;1.0->checkstyle#checkstyle-all;5.5 [default->*]
[ivy:retrieve]          tried http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/ivy-5.5.xml
[ivy:retrieve] ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/ivy-5.5.xml
[ivy:retrieve]          tried http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/checkstyle-all-5.5.jar
[ivy:retrieve] ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/checkstyle-all-5.5.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ETHZ-HTTP: no ivy file nor artifact found for checkstyle#checkstyle-all;5.5
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    module not found: checkstyle#checkstyle-all;5.5
[ivy:retrieve] WARN: ==== ETHZ-HTTP: tried
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:   http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/ivy-5.5.xml
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:   -- artifact checkstyle#checkstyle-all;5.5!checkstyle-all.jar:
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:   http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/checkstyle-all-5.5.jar
```

Now there are **no** firewalls or proxies involved and the URLs are accessible without problems with other tools (e.g., a browser, curl, wget, ...). For example:

```
$ curl http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/ivy-5.5.xml
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="checkstyle" module="checkstyle-all" revision="5.5" status="integration" publication="20120806133612"/>
        <publications>
                <artifact name="checkstyle-all" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
        </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

On the server side the logs show nothing: no errors not even a connection

**EDIT** `ivysettings.xml` should be OK since they can be used without problems with Mac OS X and Linux:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings  defaultResolver = "ETHZ-HTTP" >
        <caches defaultCacheDir = "${ivy.settings.dir}/ivy-cache" />
    </settings>
    <resolvers>
        <url name="ETHZ-HTTP">
            <ivy      pattern="http://ivy.ethz.ch/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].xml" />
            <artifact pattern="http://ivy.ethz.ch/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Any hint?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but everything works fine for me.

Comment: @oers Yes I see your access in the server log file ... Thanks it helps to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a firewall on your Windows machine which is blocking Java from doing any network ?

Try this simple ant build.xml file to test it:

```
<project>
    <get src="http://ivy.ethz.ch/checkstyle/checkstyle-all/5.5/ivy-5.5.xml" dest="ivy-5.5.xml" />
</project>
```